# Reading large text file freezes Excel, can it be done using Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am importing data via a SQL import code through Excel VBA to `sheet6`. I am then looping through each row of the imported data looking for a match based on two criteria. Column A and column G value being present in a line from a large text file with 2 million lines of data. If a match is found then the first value from the comma delimited text file is added to column E.

I have tried researching Excel VBA codes, but it is really slow when looping through 5000 rows of data. It can take up to 30 mins to run. Hoping that maybe a Python solution could be the answer.

```vb
Const strFileName = "T:\Hex\ModeS-Mil.txt"

Sub FillMTextFile()
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim strsearch As String
Dim MReg As String
Dim MType As String
Dim strLine As String
Dim f As Integer
Dim lngLine As Long
Dim blnFound As Boolean
Dim x As Long
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Sheet6.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
StartTime = Timer
For x = 2 To 3000
MReg = Sheet6.Range("A" & x).Value
MType = Sheet6.Range("G" & x).Value
strsearch = MReg & "," & MType
f = FreeFile
Open strFileName For Input As #f
Do While Not EOF(f)
lngLine = lngLine + 1
Line Input #f, strLine
If InStr(1, strLine, strsearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
Sheet6.Range("E" & x).Value = UCase(Split(strLine, ",")(0))
On Error GoTo err
blnFound = True
Exit Do
End If
Loop
Close #f
If Not blnFound Then
End If
err:
Next x
SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "code time " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent code when posting.

Comment: It would help to give examples of the spreadsheet data you're parsing through, and the first few lines of the text file you're searching.

Comment: Data from imported sql into workbook that requires a match

Comment: Column A A40-034
A40-035
A40-032
A40-041
A40-042
A40-040
A40-005
A40-006
A40-016
A40-018
A40-019
A40-020
A40-024
A40-025
A40-027

Comment: Column G AS55
S61
S61
S61
MI24
UH1
B06
NH90
NH90
NH90
NH90
NH90
NH90
NH90
NH90

Comment: An example is search Col A:  A40-040 and Col G :  NH90 , look in comma delimited  text file 7CF896,A40-040,NH90 add first text 7CF896 to Column E

Comment: Please not that if you `Dim MReg, MType As String` only `MType` is of type `String` but `MReg` is of type `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable `Dim MReg As String, MType As String` or it is automatically `Variant` (which is the worst choice). • Please also include your addional data in the question itself instead of multiple comments (so you can format and explain it better). Screenshots can help too.

Comment: Thanks I amended the code above , but it still runs to slow in excel. The main issue is if there is no match then it has to check each line of the 2 million rows of data. So when I am looping 2000 times , in excel it can take up to 30 mins to complete. Is there a way to do this in python. or a better way in excel

Answer (score 0):

Whether this approach works is based on whether all of the following are true:

- You can specify in advance which columns in your CSV correspond to columns A and G of `Sheet6`
- You can specify in advance which column of your CSV you want to write to column E of `Sheet6`
- None of the values themselves in your CSV contain any new line characters or commas.

I hope that all makes sense. ^

```
Option Explicit

Const CSV_FILE_PATH As String = "T:\Hex\ModeS-Mil.txt"
Const FIRST_ROW_CONTAINING_DATA As Long = 2 ' Exclude header row'

Sub FillMTextFile()

    Dim csvMap As Collection
    Set csvMap = GetMapForCsv()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheet6.Cells(Sheet6.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Assert lastRow >= FIRST_ROW_CONTAINING_DATA

    Dim substringsInColumnA() As Variant ' This needs a better name, especially if your columns change.'
    substringsInColumnA = Sheet6.Range("A" & FIRST_ROW_CONTAINING_DATA, "A" & lastRow).Value

    Dim substringsInColumnG() As Variant ' This needs a better name, especially if your columns change.'
    substringsInColumnG = Sheet6.Range("G" & FIRST_ROW_CONTAINING_DATA, "G" & lastRow).Value

    Dim outputRowCount As Long
    outputRowCount = lastRow - FIRST_ROW_CONTAINING_DATA + 1

    Dim arrayToWriteToSheet() As String
    ReDim arrayToWriteToSheet(1 To outputRowCount, 1 To 1)
    Debug.Assert LBound(arrayToWriteToSheet, 1) = LBound(substringsInColumnA, 1)

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    For rowIndex = LBound(substringsInColumnA, 1) To UBound(substringsInColumnA, 1)

        Dim substringsToJoin(0 To 1) As String ' Static, re-use every iteration'
        substringsToJoin(0) = UCase$(CStr(substringsInColumnA(rowIndex, 1)))
        substringsToJoin(1) = UCase$(CStr(substringsInColumnG(rowIndex, 1)))

        Dim substringToSearchFor As String
        substringToSearchFor = Join$(substringsToJoin, ",")

        arrayToWriteToSheet(rowIndex, 1) = _
            GetCollectionItemOrDefault(someCollection:=csvMap, someKey:=substringToSearchFor)

    Next rowIndex

    Sheet6.Cells(FIRST_ROW_CONTAINING_DATA, "E").Resize(UBound(arrayToWriteToSheet, 1), UBound(arrayToWriteToSheet, 2)) = arrayToWriteToSheet
End Sub

Private Function GetMapForCsv() As Collection
    ' This function tries to take advantage of which columns '
    ' in the CSV to look at -- and builds a collection in which: '
    '   • each collection key = the concatenation of columns that need to contain matches '
    '   • each collection item = the value that we later want to look up '

    Const CSV_COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO_COLUMN_E As Long = 1 ' First column'
    Const CSV_COLUMN_CORRESPONDING_TO_COLUMN_A As Long = 2 ' Second column'
    Const CSV_COLUMN_CORRESPONDING_TO_COLUMN_G As Long = 3 ' Third column'

    Dim outputCollection As Collection
    Set outputCollection = New Collection

    Dim fileHandle As Long
    fileHandle = FreeFile

    Open CSV_FILE_PATH For Input As #fileHandle ' Open once outside of loop.'
    Do Until EOF(fileHandle)

        ' File is probably too large to fit in memory, hence iterating line by line'
        ' but I think this assumes there are no escaped/quoted new line characters in the values themselves'
        Dim currentLineInCsv As String
        Line Input #fileHandle, currentLineInCsv
        currentLineInCsv = UCase$(currentLineInCsv)

        Dim currentValues() As String
        currentValues = Split(currentLineInCsv, ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)

        Dim toJoin(0 To 1) As String
        toJoin(0) = currentValues(CSV_COLUMN_CORRESPONDING_TO_COLUMN_A - 1) ' 0-based array assumed'
        toJoin(1) = currentValues(CSV_COLUMN_CORRESPONDING_TO_COLUMN_G - 1) ' 0-based array assumed'

        Dim collectionKey As String
        collectionKey = Join$(toJoin, ",")

        Dim collectionItem As String
        collectionItem = currentValues(CSV_COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO_COLUMN_E - 1) ' 0-based array assumed'

        On Error Resume Next
        outputCollection.Add Item:=collectionItem, key:=collectionKey
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Close #fileHandle

    Set GetMapForCsv = outputCollection
End Function

Private Function GetCollectionItemOrDefault(ByVal someCollection As Collection, ByVal someKey As String, Optional ByVal defaultValue As String = vbNullString) As String
    ' Returns the item corresponding to some key of a collection'
    ' If the key does not exist, returns the default.'

    Dim keyDoesNotExist As Boolean
    Dim itemToReturn As String

    On Error Resume Next
    itemToReturn = someCollection(someKey)
    keyDoesNotExist = (Err.Number <> 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If keyDoesNotExist Then itemToReturn = defaultValue
    GetCollectionItemOrDefault = itemToReturn
End Function
```

Regarding implementation, you will need to change these lines (in the code for `GetMapForCsv` function):

```
Const CSV_COLUMN_TO_WRITE_TO_COLUMN_E As Long = 1 ' First column'
Const CSV_COLUMN_CORRESPONDING_TO_COLUMN_A As Long = 2 ' Second column'
Const CSV_COLUMN_CORRESPONDING_TO_COLUMN_G As Long = 3 ' Third column'
```

so that the assignments are true for your CSV. Currently, the above assignments assume that:

- the second column in your CSV corresponds to the values in `Sheet6`'s column A
- the third column in your CSV corresponds to the values in `Sheet6`'s column G
- you want to look up the values in the first column of your CSV and write them to `Sheet6`'s column E.

My CSV contained only 3 columns, my `Sheet6` contained 10k values to look up; and on my machine the code above took:

- ~195.6 seconds for 10 million rows in CSV
- ~35.2 seconds for 2 million rows in CSV

---

Alternative approaches might include:

- Using Python. It should be possible to use a generator expression to loop over the CSV file's 2 million rows in a memory-efficient manner. I think the built-in `csv` module could handle this task, but you might also need some Python module/library to interface with Excel e.g. `openpyxl`, `XlsxWriter` (so that you can read the values in columns A and G). The Python code would probably be much shorter/easier to maintain.
- Using Power Query (which is has been part of Excel on Windows for several years now). You could potentially read columns A and G into one table -- and the CSV into another table. The output would probably be loaded as a table to a worksheet. Not sure how performant/efficient it would be, but it might be worth setting up your data in a way that allows you to use `Table.Merge`. Otherwise, maybe you could fall back to `Text.Contains` or something.

Comment: I tried the VBA code and it comes up with a Run-time error 9  for arrayToWriteToSheet(writeIndex, 1) = Left$(currentLineInCsv, indexOfFirstComma) this was from row 3336

Comment: @JohnD, sounds like `arrayToWriteToSheet` had 3336 rows, and now the code is trying to access the 3337th row -- which doesn't exist and so gives an error. I think if the CSV contains multiple matches for a given row, then all of those matches will be added to `arrayToWriteToSheet`. But the code expects no more than 1 match, which is why it's breaking.

Comment: Also, I think that line should be: `arrayToWriteToSheet(writeIndex, 1) = Left$(currentLineInCsv, indexOfFirstComma - 1)`, otherwise it will include the comma (have changed my code to reflect this).

Comment: @JohnD, are you expecting the first match only, or do you want all matches? Hope my question makes sense

Comment: There will be some occaisions when there is no match of data , is this what is causing the error

Comment: @JohnD, no, I think the problem is that some values in columns A and G match multiple lines in the CSV (but my code assumed there would be 0 or 1 match at most). You can check by putting something like `Debug.Assert writeIndex  <= ubound(arrayToWriteToSheet, 1)` after this line `writeIndex = writeIndex + 1` and then seeing if the code's execution pauses on the newly added `Debug.Assert` line.

Comment: If there are 0 matches, no value will be written to column E. If there is 1 match, 1 value will be written to column E. If there is more than 1 match, do you only want the first match -- or do you want all matches to be written to column E?

Comment: it would be great if you could not add a value if there is more than 1 match

Comment: @JohnD, I've re-written my answer. My previous code had a bug (`arrayToWriteToSheet` was declared incorrectly) and the procedure's overall logic was more inefficient than I thought (as I did not `Exit` the loop once a match was found).

Comment: thanks it took only 35 seconds to run using your code. I am trying work out how your code works , as I am also looking to use another search by just one code in column A looking for a match in a text file , with two columns of data. seperated by a comma. first column has unique codes that need to be matched and when matched add value in column 2 of text file  to column E. Is this possible by adapting your code

Comment: @JohnD, the code is somewhat specialised to perform the lookup you described in your original post, hence it's faster (since there is less indirection/abstraction) but the code is also less reusable. So performing a different lookup would probably require re-writing the code to be more dynamic/flexible -- which I can't do at the moment. Also, there may be faster ways of doing this. I think you're basically just doing a left outer join (in terms of SQL), with your columns in `Sheet6` forming the left table and the columns in the CSV forming the right table.